# ListView - highlight color of a tapped row

Tags: android, listview

I have a `ListView` with custom rows. They have different background colors set in the `ArrayAdapter` inside the `getView()` method:

`row.setBackgroundColor(R.color.list_bg);`

After setting the color, I'm loosing the highlight color/animation of a tapped row.
If I add some transparency to the background, I can see the highlight and the animation, but that's not how i'd like to solve this.

Is it possible, to somehow set a "highlight color"?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can set custom background on your row by creating an drawable with your colors or images. like make an drawable in `res/drawable/`

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item android:state_pressed="true">
        <shape android:shape="rectangle">
            <solid android:color="@color/colorPressEffect"/>
        </shape>
    </item>
    <item android:state_pressed="false">
        <shape android:shape="rectangle">
            <solid android:color="@android:color/transparent"/>
        </shape>
    </item>
</selector>
```

and just set this drawable as background on your row layout parent layout.like

```
 <LinearLayout 
        ...
        ...
         android:background="@drawable/background"
        >
```

You can achieve any animation on click by this way, the more you put effort in drawable the more you will get on click.

Comment: Thank you. That helped me. Now, I was able to also implement the ripple animation effect.